# Prevent iPhone from reducing video quality <input type=“file”>

Tags: javascript, html, ios

I am building a web app that lets a user upload a video to a server. I use for the user to select their file. They get these upload options:

If they choose to take a video in safari, the quality is greatly reduced to 480×360

I want to know if it is possible to disable this compression - I want them to have the ability to upload videos in their actual size, uncompressed. I have tried searching google with no avail.

Comment: More than a year later, I'm still trying to find this out as well.